# copy ListItems sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-list

I have two lists 
list A & List B 
I need to copy all ListItem from List A to List B 
List A & List B are in two  different subsites but in the same server

Answer (score 2):

There are different ways to transfer the data.

From PowerShell:

```
Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell -EA SilentlyContinue

$Site1URL = "http://webApp1:11111/site1/" 
$Site2URL = "http://webApp2:22222/site2/" 
$SourceList = "List A"
$DestinationList = "List B"

$Web1 = Get-SPWeb $Site1URL
$Web2 = Get-SPWeb $Site2URL
$ListA = $Web1.Lists.TryGetList($SourceList)
$ListB = $Web2.Lists.TryGetList($DestinationList)

$ListA.Items | foreach {
    $newItem = $ListB.Items.Add()
    $newItem["Col1"] = $_["Col1"]
    $newItem["Col2"] = $_["Col2"]
    $newItem.Update()
}
```